# Why does this code using Scrapy to scrape a website that requires login refuse to run and show a 403 status code?

Tags: python, scrapy

Does anyone have an idea why this code has refused to run?
In the code there you'll find all the parameters in the payload but when I crawl the spider it still shows a 403 status code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class HiddenDataLoginSpider(Spider):
    name = 'images'
    login_url = 'https://secure.classmates.com/auth/login'

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = self.login_url

    def start_requests(self):

        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        token = response.css("form[id*=login-form] input[name*=csrf]::attr(value)").extract_first()
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata={'_csrf': token,
                                                  'successUrl': ' ',
                                                  'g-recaptcha-response': ' ',
                                                  'emailOrRegId': 'user@mail.com',
                                                  'password': 'some password',
                                                  'rememberme': 'yes'
                                                  },
                                        callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        # Insert code to start scraping pages once logged in
        print(response.css('h3'))
```

Comment: From TOS: `Do not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access the Services, using automated means, such as scripts, bots, robots, spiders or scrapers`

Comment: Can you answer the question??

Comment: SO doesn't encourage answer questions that violate policies.  It's quite possible they have spider-detection code to prevent people from stealing their intellectual property.

Answer (score -1):

Website detected you as a scraper and is blocking your requests.Bear on mind that that is their legitimate strategy for many reasons. You can try to randomize your requests,use fake user agents and optimize headers.

More on this in
[stealth web scraping](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/stealth-web-scraping-in-python-avoid-blocking-like-a-ninja#user-agent-header)